# Impressão fibonacci recursivo

Tags: c, recursão

Estou com problemas com a função fibonacci recursiva, no exercício pede-se pra imprimir dentro da função ou mesmo usando uma função recursiva auxiliar, porém não pode imprimir na função main, tentei de tudo pra impressão, porém eles ficam se repetindo, a função fibonacci recursiva eu sei fazer, só falta a impressão, segue o enunciando e peço que alguém me dê uma luz.

> "A Sequência de Fibonacci é definida por:
>
> - F0 = 0
> - F1 = 1
> - Fn = F<sub>n - 1</sub> + F<sub>n - 2</sub>, para n > 1
>
> Desenvolva uma função recursiva que calcula e imprime os n primeiros
>   números da Sequência de Fibonacci. A função deve ter a seguinte assinatura:
>
> ```
> int fibonacci (int n);
> ```
>
> A função deve imprimir os n primeiros números separados por espaços, por
>   exemplo, para n = 10:
>
> 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34"

Comment: Só para dizer que existem outras formas além da recursão:
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/177138/como-otimizar-essa-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-sequ%C3%AAncia-de-fibonacci/177269

Comment: Só quero deixar claro que Fibonacci é um exemplo de onde **não** se deve usar recursão, ao menos não sem algum outro truque. Veja a pergunta que o @MarcusBecker linkou acima para mais detalhes.

Comment: É obrigatório o uso de recursão, são exercícios de teste sobre o conteúdo. Tmb não gosto de recursão com fibonacci, é muito longa a execução, mas é um curso e esse é o tema

Comment: @MarcelodeSousa Sim, eu sei. O meu comentário acima foi só para deixar claro para algum visitante casual que esbarrar nessa pergunta que usar recursão no Fibonacci de forma simples e direta não é uma boa ideia.

Answer (score 2):

Lembre-se do que se trata a função ela é a soma do antecessor pelo antecessor anterior , ela começa com dois termos o 0 e o 1.

- fórmula : 0, 1,(1+0),((1+0)+1),(((1+0)+1)+(1+0))....

transformando essa expressão em uma função podemos chegar em  Fibro(n - 1) + Fibro(n - 2) onde n é o número de termos considerando , é claro , que ela esta sendo feita de forma decrescente (para que precise passar só um valor de parâmetro).

feita recursivamente cada soma dos seus termos será armazenada em uma pilha que após chegar na condição de base será encerrada e terá seus termos desempilhados.

obs: deixo um exemplo em C# , o raciocínio é o mesmo

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n=0;
        Console.WriteLine("Digite o tamanho da sequencia");
        n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("resultado");
        for (int c=0; c<=n; c++) {
          Console.Write(" "+Fibro(c + 1));//imprimi aqui mas você pode imprimir dentro da recursão mas vai perder o objetivo da recursão de mostrar uma pilha 
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    public static int Fibro(int n){
        if (n == 1 || n == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else {

            return Fibro(n - 1) + Fibro(n - 2);//recursão 

        }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Se só falta a impressão, cada vez que você calcular o valor do número basta

```
printf("Fibonacci é: %d", fibonacci);
```

Onde %d é apenas um "holder" pro seu número, que é passado no segundo parametro.

Comment: Vc fala dentro da função? Aqui testei e nada, como disse a impressão tem que ser dentro da função ou usando uma função auxiliar

Comment: Dentro do seu método recursivo, antes de chamar fibonacci novamente de um print do seu número. Deve funcionar... Caso contrário poste o seu código atual @MarcelodeSousa

Answer (score 0):

Essa é uma versão do algoritmo de fibonacci utilizando um vetor auxiliar, que possibilita o cálculo de valores até 50, instantaneamente. Para valores maiores, será necessário o uso de long int, long long int ou outros.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

void calculaFibonnaci();
int fibonnaci();

int vetor[1000];

void calculaFibonnaci(int i) { 

    if(i==1 || i==2) {
        vetor[i] = 1;
    }
    else { 
        vetor[i] = fibonnaci(i-1) + fibonnaci(i-2);
    }
}

int fibonnaci(int i)
{
    if(vetor[i]==0) {
        calculaFibonnaci(i);
        printf("%d ", vetor[i]);
    }
    else {
        return vetor[i];
    }   
} 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    int i, N;
    int *vetor;
    printf("Digite quantos termos da série de fibonacci você deseja: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    for(i=1; i<=N; i++)
        fibonnaci(i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Se você reparar no meu comentário da linha 3, vai ver que terá problemas para valores grandes, por exemplo, 40, 45. Se quiser aprimorar seu fibonnaci recursivo, recomendo uma pesquisa sobre o uso de um vetor para armazenar os valores já calculados, evitando o recálculo.

Comment: Não posso usar a função main como auxiliar, a função main deve chamar a função recursiva fibonacci e usar uma função auxiliar dentro da rescursiva, a função fibonacci deve chamar a função para impressão, sem passar pelo main ou imprimir dentro dela mesmo

Comment: Calma, implementei o uso do vetor, mas acho que isso ainda não resolve teu problema.

Comment: Pronto, acredito que agora seu problema esteja resolvido.

Comment: A assinatura da função tem que ser int fibonacci (int n); e sem o uso do main, a função principal deve ser usada apenas para chamar a função recursiva.

Comment: Essa solução é mais inteligente porque permite o cálculo de fibonnaci para valores grandes. Vou adaptá-la para entrar no conforme do seu exercício

Comment: Só por curiosidade, você poderia criar um vetor global, driblando essa necessidade de ser int fibonnaci (int n);

Comment: A assinatura  int fibonnaci (int n); é obrigatória, mas pode ser usado um vetor global sim

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51899/discussion-between-gabriel-pellegrino-and-marcelo-de-sousa).

Comment: Pronto, agora está com um vetor global, de acordo com seu enunciado.

Comment: A função main não pode imprimir nada.

Answer (score -1):

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int fib(int n){

```
if(n == 0){
    
    return 0;
    
}
if(n < 3){
    
    return 1;   
    
}else{
    
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);

}
```

}

int main(void){

```
int n;
int r;
int i;

scanf("%d", &n);

for(i = 0; i <= n; i++){
    
    r = fib(i);
    
    printf("%d ", r);       
}



return 0;
```

}

Answer (score -3):

Série Fibonacci em C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned long fibonacci();
unsigned long v[sizeof(int)] ;

unsigned long fibonacci(int n) {
   if (n <= 0)
      return -1;
   if((n <= 2)  && v[n] == 0) {
      v[n] = 1;
      printf("%lu ", v[n]);
   }
   else if (v[n] == 0) {
      v[n] = fibonacci(n-2) + fibonacci(n-1);
      printf("%lu ", v[n]);
   }

   return v[n];
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   int in;
   printf("Entre com o tamanho da série: ");
   scanf("%d", &in);
   fibonacci(in);
   return 0;
}
```

Série Fibonacci em Python:

```
d = {}
def fib(n):
  if (n < 2):
    d[n] = n
    return d[n]
  if (d.keys().__contains__(n)):
    return d[n]    
  d[n] = fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1)    
  return d[n]  

for i in range(0,101):
  print('fib(',i,'): ', fib(i))
```

Comment: Antônio, a pergunta é em C e você não está explicando como seu código funciona para que o autor entenda e reproduza em outra linguagem.