# Sequência de Fibonacci recursiva

Tags: java, recursão

Estou estudando Java e preciso fazer um programa de Fibonacci recursivo, mas não tenho nem ideia de como fazer isso. Por favor, se você sabe, me ajude. Aqui está um código indutivo:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 5, i = 0, a = 0, b = 1;
    System.out.print( a + " " + b + " ");
    while(i<=n){
        int c = a + b;
        System.out.print(c + " ");
        a = b;
        b = c;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177138/132

Comment: Acho que você deveria tentar resolver esse problema por conta própria. É um problema simples. Você chegou a estudar recursão? Se você tivesse alguma dúvida sobre a recursão, acredito que nesse caso caberia uma pergunta. Ao que parece você recebeu o problema e o colocou aqui na íntegra, não mostrando nenhuma tentativa de resolução.

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta pois como dito, não há dúvidas sobre programação, e sim a resolução do seu problema [facilmente encontrado na internet](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3316/recursividade-em-java.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

A chamada recursiva a Fibonacci é bastante simples:

```
class Fibonacci {
    public static long fibonacci(int n) {
        return n < 2 ? n : fibonacci(n - 2) + fibonacci(n - 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Fibonacci(" + i + ") = " + fibonacci(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
Fibonacci(0) = 0
Fibonacci(1) = 1
Fibonacci(2) = 1
Fibonacci(3) = 2
Fibonacci(4) = 3
Fibonacci(5) = 5
Fibonacci(6) = 8
Fibonacci(7) = 13
Fibonacci(8) = 21
Fibonacci(9) = 34
Fibonacci(10) = 55
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/iB63oH)

Entretanto, o Fibonacci é um exemplo clássico de um problema onde o uso de recursão é uma estratégia muito ruim e tem um desempenho péssimo. O uso por iteração (com `while` ou `for`) é bastante superior. Veja mais detalhes sobre isso [**nesta outra resposta minha**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/177175/132).

Comment: Código limpo! Fácil compreensão! Parabéns!