# Número de chamadas função recursiva

Tags: c, recursão

Olá. Como poderia saber quantas vezes uma função é chamada recursivamente pelo seu código?

Por exemplo, no código abaixo, como saber quantos asteriscos a função imprime para um dado valor n?

```
int fibonacci(int n) {
    printf("*");
    if ((n == 1) || (n == 2))
        return (1);
    return (fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2));
}
```

Comment: É só ter uma variável que controle isto, como tudo que deseja um estado, mas depende de como quer isto para saber como fazer. De qualquer forma quando começa ter muita complicação é melhor não fazer recursivo.

Comment: Uma variável global não ajuda?

Comment: Então, na verdade eu queria uma expressão matemática para isso.
Por exemplo, para n = 3 imprime 3 asteristos, para n = 5 imprime 9
f(3) = 3
f(5) = 9

Não quero que o programa faça isso. Quero uma forma de eu entender como se calcula esse número.

Comment: Você está interessado na complexidade do seu algoritmo? Se for é interessante que inclua isto em sua pergunta...

Comment: Isso, acredtio que seja isso que eu quero.

Comment: Se for para usar uma variável global não faz sentido fazer algo recursivo.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como otimizar essa função para sequência de Fibonacci?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/177138/como-otimizar-essa-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-para-sequ%c3%aancia-de-fibonacci)

Comment: Embora a pergunta que marquei como duplicata seja de Javascript ao invés de C, o código de lá tem o mesmo funcionamento e as respostas de lá devem servir para responder a sua pergunta.

Comment: Permita-me perguntar: você quer saber isso para qualquer função? Por exemplo, "quero saber quantas vezes minha função `int quadrado (int n)` foi chamada"? Se for isso, acredito que você poderia usar ferramentas mais profissionais, como o [GCOV](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov.html).

Comment: Na verdade isso é um exercício, foi dada uma questão: "No programa abaixo, quantas vezes * é impresso para uma entrada n?"

Answer (score 1):

é facil, você pode criar uma variavel para contar isso:

```
int qtd = 0;

int fibonacci(int n) {
    qtd += 1;
    printf("chamado: %d \n", qtd);
    if ((n == 1) || (n == 2))
        return (1);
    return (fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2));
}
```

Testado no site [online_c_compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler)

Comment: Esse código conta quantas vezes a função é chamada e não quantas vezes é chamada recursivamente. Por exemplo, com `n=3` a função vai fazer 2 chamadas recursivas, `fibonacci(3-1)` e  `fibonacci(3-2)`.

Comment: @Jorge B. é só decrementar o contador antes de imprimir...

Answer (score 0):

Acho que dá pra colocar o segundo return dentro de um 'else' e assim acrescentar a variável de contagem

```
int qtd = 0, aux = 0;

int fibonacci(int n) {
    printf("*");
    if ((n == 1) || (n == 2)){
        return (1);
    qtd = aux ; /*Recebe o número de chamadas recursivas, vc decide como usar essa 
    variável no resto do código rsrsrs, é essa variável que vai conter o valor que 
    você quer*/ 

    aux = 0; //Zerei a variável para o caso de vc chamar a função de novo

}
    else{
    return (fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2));
    aux++;
    }
}
```